# Is this understanding of the "Git file status lifecycle" correct?

Tags: git

The Git file status lifecycle has confused me for a while, so I've been trying to go back [to the page on the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) to make sense of it. I wasn't able to parse the diagram that they created in the book, so after reading through I created my own:

[image]

My understanding is this:

- When you create a file, it is "untracked"
- When you use `git add` to add it to the staging area, it becomes "staged"
- If you edit the file at this stage, it becomes both "staged" and "modified", because part of its content is tracked in the staging area, and part of its content is recorded in the working directory.
- To resolve this, use `git add` to transition the file back to "staged"
- When you use `git commit`, that file becomes "unmodified", also "committed" - because it wasn't modified since the commit you just created
- When you subsequently edit the file you've just created, it becomes "modified"
- If you stage that file using `git add`, it once again becomes "staged", and the lifecycle can begin anew.
- If for some reason you wish to untrack a file that is staged at any point, you can use `git restore --staged 1` to remove it from the index (thanks `git status` for reminding me that this is a thing!). I'm not sure it's worth plotting out all of the other ways you can remove a file into this diagram though.

Basically: is my understanding correct, and does this diagram accurately show the stages a file can go through? Or have I missed an important step or captured this incorrectly?

Comment: @torek is this your book?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking @evolutionxbox - the diagram I've posted is my own, and the link I've posted is to Scott Chacon's Git book. Or are you just asking if this is torek's area of expertise? (torekspertise if you will)

Comment: Sorry I was tagging a user on SO who wrote a git-pro book. I had thought the linked one was theirs, but you've corrected me.

Comment: Ah no prob! I'd be interested to read their book as torek has answered at least one of my questions on Git with a beautiful level of  expertise and knowledge previously.

Comment: Chiming in... I think you have a good working understanding, yes. There's a subtlety your diagram doesn't have: "Staged" can be already tracked (i.e., previously committed), with changes staged, or untracked, with a initial version staged. But I wouldn't see value in changing your graph to reflect that.

Comment: @joanis I'm not quite clear on your explanation, and it seems to contradict my understanding. ""Staged" can be already tracked (i.e., previously committed)" <-- I thought that if a file is committed, it could not be "staged" at the same time. If it's committed and you subsequently modify and stage it *then* it would be staged, no? Also to my understanding "staged" and "untracked" are mutually exclusive, no? As a staged file is by definition tracked? I'm sure I've misunderstood what you're trying to explain though

Comment: Yes, a file can be simultaneously committed and staged. If you modify a committed file, you get to your Modified state, and then git add brings you back to Staged, but that doesn't remove the committed file, you just have two versions of it, one in the the previous commit and a different one staged in the index.

Comment: You're right, though, as soon as you git add a new file, `git status` no longer considers it "untracked" because you've declared that you want to track it with that `git add` operation, so my comment was not quite right. What I wanted to distinguish was previously committed vs not previously committed, and I should not have called the latter untracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that *staged*, as a verb (past tense), has, at best, a peculiar and weak meaning.  *Stage* (as a verb, present tense, the act of "staging") *does* have a pretty clear meaning: it means you're running `git add`.

The tricky part here is that `git status` talks about *changes staged for commit* (or `to be committed`, in the version of Git below) and *changes not staged for commit*, and yet—well, watch this series of commands:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   Makefile
```

At this point, Git says that I have a "change to be committed".  What I did was change the first line of the `Makefile` to add a space at the front, and run `git add` to stage it.

But now I'll *undo* my change, which of course happens first in the working tree:

```
$ ed Makefile
113650
1s/^ //
w
113649
q
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   Makefile

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Makefile
```

I now have two *different* sets of changes.  Some are "to be committed" and some are "not staged for commit".  Let's *stage* them with `git add`:

```
$ git add Makefile
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Wait, what?  Staging something unstaged everything?!  This is where that whole "changes vs snapshots" is-it-a-wave is-it-a-particle duality issue shows up.  The way to make sense of this is to know that Git *stores* snapshots, but often *shows* changes.

#### Snapshots vs changes

Here's an obvious sequence of integers: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...  We're just *counting*, and the *difference between* any two integers is always 1.  But do we start with zero, or one?<sup>1</sup>  If the only thing we know is that it *always goes up by one*, we can't know where it starts (at zero, or one, or maybe a negative or larger positive number).  If we know *where it starts*—say, at zero—*and* that it always goes up by one, we're good.

Or, we could just store every number every time.  Then, if we're curious about how much it went up, we subtract.  It's five now, it was four last time: aha, it went up by 1!  Later, it's 98227 now and was 98226 yesterday: aha, it went up by 1 again!

Maybe the sequence is less obvious: maybe it goes 0, 1, 50, 12, 241, and so on.  But if we know we start with zero, and the first time we *add* 1, then we *add* 49, then we *add* negative-thirty-eight (or subtract 38), and so on, that works.  Again, we can either start from a known state—say, always zero—and store *everything* as a *change*, or we can just store everything.

This same rule works for version control.  We can start with "there are no files", and we can store everything as a *change:* the first snapshot is made by adding some files, the second snapshot is made by subtracting certain lines from particular files and adding other lines to other files, and so on.  Some early version control systems did just this.  It works pretty well, for some files at least, as a compression mechanism, too: this is a form of [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).

It has one obvious drawback.  If we want the *latest* version of the files—which is a pretty common thing to want—we have to start from zero, read *every change*, and *build up* the final version of each file.  This is such an obvious drawback that some early version control systems reversed the approach: they stored the *latest* file intact, and stored "backwards deltas" saying how to make changes to work backwards, one step at a time.<sup>2</sup>

**Git throws all this right out the window.**  Instead of storing *deltas*, Git stores *snapshots*.  Every commit just holds a full copy of every file.  This, of course, wastes tons of disk space—so Git secretly *de-duplicates* files *and*, later, uses a variant of delta-compression with limited chain lengths to further compress its internal objects.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>[Or, perhaps, one half?](https://twitter.com/codewisdom/status/806529463395741696)

<sup>2</sup>This gets tricky once you start branching and merging, but it saves a lot of time in terms of getting the *latest* files.  RCS in particular used reverse deltas in the trunk and forward deltas in branches.

<sup>3</sup>This is similar to what Mercurial does, which is to store either a snapshot *or* a delta depending on how long the delta-chain has gotten.  Git's method is rather more dynamic though, throwing processing power at the problem with a "do it later" attitude—e.g., compress the files while nobody is working—rather than "while storing the file", which is of course while someone is working.

---

#### That's fine for commits, but what about staging?

Having gone in for snapshots, Git milks this idea for all it's worth: the *staging area*, which is one of three terms Git has for what it also calls the *index* or the *cache*, holds a snapshot.

The snapshot *in* the index is *separate from all the other snapshots*.  It uses the same *format* as commits—de-duplicated "blob" objects—to hold the file data, but a different format from commits to hold the file's names.  Commits use nested trees, while Git's index is a flat file, or sometimes a pair of files in split-index mode.  All of this is internal and you don't normally need to care about it, but it does lead to the surprise above.

Besides the snapshots in commits—which are frozen for all time—and the proposed *next* snapshot in Git's index / staging-area, there's also a snapshot, of sorts, in your *working tree*.  But *these* files are just ordinary files.  They're not in a special Gitty format.  That means that ordinary programs—your editors, compilers, Python, Java, C#, whatever—can deal with these.  They're just *files*.

**In the end, then, there are three copies of each "active" file.**  If you have checked out commit `a123456...`, and it has 100 files, there are *300* files:

- there's one of each, frozen in the commit;
- there's one of each in Git's *index*, ready to go into the *next* commit; and
- there's one of each in your working tree, so that you can see it and work on / with it.

The "copies" in Git's index are pre-de-duplicated, so initially, when they're all duplicates, they literally take no space.<sup>4</sup>  So there's no real cost to the extra copies.  But they do give rise to this weirdness.

The `git add` command—the one we use to "stage" a file—simply *reads the working tree copy* and compresses it into the internal, de-duplicated (and zlib compressed) form that Git uses as a minimum compression mechanism.  It then writes that compressed file, unless it *is* a duplicate, in which case it throws out the compressed file and uses the existing duplicate.

So if we take a file out of a commit with `git checkout`, we have our three copies.  We modify a bit of the file and now we have two identical copies:

- the commit and index match
- the working tree version is different

and `git status` tells us this, by *comparing* the commit and index ("what's staged?") and then, separately, *comparing* the index and working tree ("what's not-yet-staged?").

Then we run `git add` to "stage our changes".  Git compresses and de-duplicates and writes the file and now we still have two versions:

- the committed copy is unchanged, as always
- the index and working tree copies match each other but differ from the committed one

and `git status` tells us this: there's no *difference* between "staged" (index) version and working version, so it's just "staged for commit".

If we now make an "undo" change in the *working tree* copy—that's what I did—and run `git add`, Git copies the working tree copy back into the index as usual.  This time, though, the compressed copy *is* a duplicate, of what was and still is in the commit.  So now all three copies match again, and `git status` says nothing at all.

The "life cycle" is an illusion.  The underlying reality is that there are committed copies, index copies, and working-tree copies.

---

<sup>4</sup>The index entry itself takes some space, roughly about 100 bytes per file.

Comment: So to sum this up, you'd prefer to think of this as: "Changes to be committed" is the diff between the current commit/HEAD and the index; and "Changes not staged for commit" is the diff between the index and the working tree; and an empty `git status` output indicates that HEAD, the index and the working tree are all matching?

Comment: And so in the illusory lifecycle model - "Unmodified" is when all 3 trees match, whereas anything that is "Modified" is a diff of the worktree and commit, anything that is "Untracked" is a diff of the index and worktree, and anything that is "Staged" is a diff of the ... No maybe I need to think about this more...

Comment: Actually I think you've got it now. :-) Git "likes" to have a whole tree full of stuff: one commit = one tree (in the committed form), one index / staging-area = one tree (in the ready-to-commit form), and one working tree = one tree (in the usable files form).

Comment: So "Staged" is a diff of the index and the commit, is what I think I was going to say. In any case, this is a fantastic answer that goes at length to answer everything around my question, in order to ultimately frame challenge the question. But you've given me a lot of useful context that I was looking for anyway.

Comment: One thing that wasn't clear to me from what you've said though, is that the index keeps a copy of files. When I `init` a new repo, create a file, and then stage it, at that point an object is added to the repository. Then when I make a commit, the commit object and tree object are recorded in the object database, but the original object remains the same. So it seems like there are two copies: one stored in .git/objects but referenced by the index presumably when I stage it, and also referenced by the commit object when I create a commit; and then the original file in the working directory?

Comment: Technically speaking, `git add` reads the working tree copy and writes a temporary blob object to obtain its hash ID. It then looks in the existing objects DB for that hash ID. If it exists, `git add` is done with the object part and throws out the temporary blob, otherwise it puts the temporary blob in the object DB. Then `git add` updates the (new, in-progress, temporary) index to have the new blob object entry, and if all has gone well all the way through this operation, swaps the new index file into place with an atomic `rename` system call.

Comment: The end result is a single blob object with the right hash ID and the right entry in the index, so that the index and DB hold the new or re-used object, and there's just one Git-ized copy. The working tree copy isn't modified in the process of compressing to a temporary blob object, so it remains untouched.